# Hadoop InputFormat for Excel

Tags: dictionary, reduce

I  need to create a  map-reducing program which reads an Excel file from HDFS and does some  analysis on it. From there store the output in the format of excel file.  I know that TextInputFormat is used to read  a .txt file from HDFS but which method or which inputformat should I have to use?

Comment: What is the use case? 
Is this a single input file?
What is it's size?
Do you use it in the excel application, or do you just use the format?
Working with excel is suitable for relatively small files
Working with hadoop is suitable for very large datasets

Comment: I need to retrieve only one Excel fiel from HDFS . The size of the file is 1913 KB. i  need to process this file in pseudo distributed single mode cluster.

Comment: Can we read  this excel file directly from hadoop cluster . What is the the inputformat type that i need to use in Job configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, hadoop is overkill for this scenario, but some relevant solutions

1. parse the file externally and convert to an hadoop compatible format
2. read the complete file as a single record [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881028/590335)
3. use two chained jobs. the 1st like in 2, reads the file in bulk, and emits each record as input for the next job.