# Hadoop Map Reduce let addInputPath work with spesific file name

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hey this is more a java question but it is related to Hadoop .

I have this line on code in my Map Reduce java Job :

```
 JobConf conf= new JobConf(WordCount.class);
 conf.setJobName("Word Count");
       .............
       .............
       .............
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
```

instead of "giving" a directory with many files how do i set specific file name ?

Comment: Have you tried  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("absolute file name")); It will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the book "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide":

> An input path is specified by calling the static addInputPath() method
>   on FileInputFormat, and it can be a single file, a directory (in which
>   case the input forms all the files in that directory), or a file
>   pattern. As the name suggests, addInputPath() can be called more than
>   once to use input from multiple paths.

So to answer your question, you should be able to just pass a path to your specific single file, and it will be used as an only input (as long as you do not do more calls of addInputPath() with some other paths).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do map-reduce stuff on one file, a quick and easy work around is to move that file only into a folder by itself and then provide that folder's path to your addInputPath.

If you're trying to read a whole file per map task then might I suggest taking a look at this post:
[Reading file as single record in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875277/reading-file-as-single-record-in-hadoop)

What exactly are you trying to do?

I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have sufficient priviledges apparently...