# How does the number of partitions affect `wholeTextFiles` and `textFiles`?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In the spark, I understand how to use `wholeTextFiles` and `textFiles`, but I'm not sure which to use when.  Here is what I know so far:

- When dealing with files that are not split by line, one should use `wholeTextFiles`, otherwise use `textFiles`.

I would think that by default, `wholeTextFiles` and `textFiles` partition by file content, and by lines, respectively.  But, both of them allow you to change the parameter `minPartitions`.

So, how does changing the partitions affect how these are processed?

For example, say I have one very large file with 100 lines.  What would be the difference between processing it as `wholeTextFiles` with 100 partiions, and processing it as `textFile` (which partitions it line by line) using the default of parition 100.

What is the difference between these?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989617/spark-sc-wholetextfiles-takes-a-long-time-to-execute

Answer (score 6):

For reference, `wholeTextFiles` uses `WholeTextFileInputFormat` which extends [CombineFileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html).

A couple of notes on `wholeTextFiles`.

- Each record in the RDD returned by `wholeTextFiles` has the file name and the entire contents of the file.  This means that a file cannot be split (at all).
- Because it extends `CombineFileInputFormat`, it will try to combine groups of smaller files into one partition.

If I have two small files in a directory, it is possible that both files will end up in a single partition.  If I set `minPartitions=2`, then I will likely get two partitions back instead.

Now if I were to set `minPartitions=3`, I will still get back two partitions because the contract for `wholeTextFiles` is that each record in the RDD contain an entire file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So, let me make sure I understand correctly:  the `InputFormat`, `splitability`, and `minPartitions` only affect how the file is converted into an RDD. Correct?          Then, after reading the input it is recommended that a particularly large `unsplittable` file be repartitioned using `repartition`, which will split the file based on hadoop `blocks`.  True?

Comment: Almost correct.  Sparks `repartition` uses an internal shuffling framework that does not take into account HDFS blocks or any specifics of the underlying storage.

Comment: Okay, so then whatever value I give for `repartition` should partition by the number that I provide it?

Comment: JavaPairRDD<String, String> wholeTextFiles = jssc.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles(args[0]); wholeTextFiles.repartition(3); WholeTextFiles is not being re-partitioned. Though i specify 3 partitions, it's taking only two partitions.

Comment: Your answer saved me. Thanks a lot.