# How to process very small files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I have about 60k file stored in HDFS, each file size is in range of kilo bytes 4kb-70kb.
Am trying to process them by performing regex search on specific files I know yet, the processing takes too long, and it seems not right ...

**the spark job is run on yarn**

**Hardware specs : 3 nodes, each has 4 core and 15G RAM**

```
targeted_files = sc.broadcast(sc.textFile(doc).collect()) # 3 files

#hdfs://hadoop.localdomain/path/to/directory/ contains ~60K files
df = sc.wholeTextFiles(
    "hdfs://hadoop.localdomain/path/to/directory/").filter(
    lambda pairRDD: ntpath.basename(pairRDD[0]) in targeted_files.value)

print('Result : ', df.collect()) #when I run this step alone, took 15 mins to finish

df = df.map(filterMatchRegex).toDF(['file_name', 'result']) # this takes ~hour and still doesn't finish
```

would be using HDFS, spark for this task is correct ?
also I thought in worst case scenario the processing time would be equal to threading approach using java ... what am I doing wrong ?

I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989617/spark-sc-wholetextfiles-takes-a-long-time-to-execute) which addresses the same problem, but am not sure how to handle it in pyspark
it seems all/most of time taken during reading files from HDFS, is there a better way to read/store small files and process them with spark ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like a right use case of spark to be honest. Your dataset is pretty small, 60k * 100k = 6 000 mB = 6 GB, which is within reason of being run on a single machine. Spark and HDFS add material overhead to processing, so the "worst case" is going to be clearly slower than a multi-threaded approach on a single machine.  In general, parallelization on a single machine (multi-threading) will be faster than parallelizing over a cluster of nodes (Spark)

Comment: yet, it doesn't even finishs, and I can't tell why

Answer (score 0):

In general the best tool to do search in a Hadoop setting is SOLR. 
It is optimized for searching, so though a tool like spark can get the job done you will never expect similar performance.

Comment: will SOLR provide parallel processing for multiple files?

Comment: @Exorcismus SOLR is indeed built to scale massively, so it can certainly work in parallel. However,  upon reviewing the other answers, I must also say that if your total dataset is only a few GB, it feels a bit odd to use a multi-node setup.

Comment: @Exorcismus Also note that solr will not read the files raw from HDFS whenever you want to do something, which may well be the bottleneck that you are hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.coalesce(20)` after loading to decrease the number of partitions and keep their size about ~128MB. Perform transformations and actions afterwards.

Comment: won't this decrease parallelism ?