# How to change the no. of mappers to be executed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

HDFS block size as per my hadoop cluster is 64MB

I have 4 small inputfiles inside a HDFS location

These 4 files are inside /user/cloudera/inputfiles directory

```
words1.txt is 1 MB of size
words2.txt is 1 MB of size 
words3.txt is 1 MB of size
words4.txt is 1 MB of size
```

I have created a simple mapreduce program for wordcount and that mapreduce program  reads all those above 4 files from the directory /user/cloudera/inputfiles

I could see that there are 4 maptasks gets executed since all those above 4 inputfiles are smaller that HDFS block size .

**Now I want to execute this mapreduce program with ONLY ONE maptask .**

Hence I applied the below  bold coding .

**conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", "134217728");**

**conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", "134217728");**

Driver program :

```
public class WordCountMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    // to remove the output directory if it exists
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    fs.delete(new Path(args[1]));
    // to remove the output directory if it exists

    conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", "134217728");
    conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", "134217728");

    //conf.set("mapred.min.split.size", "134217728");
    //conf.set("mapred.max.split.size", "134217728");
    Job job = new Job(conf);

    job.setJarByClass(WordCountMain.class);


FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);


System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0:1);



}
```

}

But if I execute this job, still I see 4 maptasks gets executed .
I would like to know why my mapreduce job still uses 4 maptasks and where do I apply the respective settings for only one map tasks to be executed.

I am running the mapreduce program as per below command

```
hadoop jar /home/myjars/WordCountMain.jar  /user/cloudera/inputfiles/  /user/cloudera/outputfiles
```

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875277/reading-file-as-single-record-in-hadoop

Comment: So the only option is CombinedFileInputFormat?

Comment: I guess so since mapreduce considers different files as different splits regardless of how tiny they are. Just a thought, if your input is ~4MB, why use mapreduce ?